# how do i wait for a webpage to finish loading everytime in uiwebview?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview

I have a number of links that are selected automatically using regex in a uiwebview. I am performing these steps in the viewdidfinishload method.  How do I wait for the current view to finish loading everytime before selecting the next link?  Do I need to use seperate webview objects or can I do all this in the same method.  There will be several seperate links automatically selected.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: **There is a method for `webviewDidfinishLoad` which is a delegate method of web view**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below As Purva said Use web view delegate for load request or error handling and so on. You can show UIActivityIndicator while start load request and stop it when request loaded successfully.

– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

– webViewDidStartLoad:

– webViewDidFinishLoad:

– webView:didFailLoadWithError:

Comment: as Purva mentioned, you will have to implment webviewDidfinishLoad method of UIWebView Delegate. [Reference][1] [1]:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thank you.  I was using the delegate but because there are so many redirects and several links to select, the webviewdidfinishload method is only good for the first one.  after that i can't figure out a way to make it do the same thing for subsequent links as they all have similar annoying redirects.

Comment: i will try the uiactivity indicator and see how that goes.

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest allow you to check URL, You can check explicit URL should load or not.